# Reduce execution time of prime number generator

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

I have to print numbers between two limits `n` and `m`, `t` times.

I created `t` variable, and two pointers `n, m` that points to reserved blocks of memory for `t` integer values.

I use pointers instead of array to do faster operations.

Outer `for` loop iterates for every test cases and increasing `m` and `n` pointers.

Inner `for` loop prints primes from `m[i]` to `n[i]`.

## Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_prime(int);

int main(void) {
    
    int t;
    int *n = malloc(sizeof(int) * t);
    int *m = malloc(sizeof(int) * t);

    scanf("%d", &t);
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++, m++, n++) {
        scanf("%d %d", &m[i], &n[i]);
        for (int j = m[i]; j <= n[i]; j++) {
            if (is_prime(j)) {
                printf("%d\n", j);
            }
        }
        if (i < t - 1) printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int is_prime(int num)
{

    if (num <= 1) return 0;
    if (num % 2 == 0 && num > 2) return 0;
     
    for(int i = 3; i < num / 2; i+= 2){
         if (num % i == 0)
             return 0;
    }
    
    return 1;
}
```

Problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

Code is correctly compiling on http://ideone.com but I'm giving "time limit exceeded" error when I'm trying submit this code on SPOJ. How can I reduce execution time of this prime number generator?

Comment: It looks like you're just doing brute-force trial division, which is incredibly slow. Look up sieves. The Wiki page on prime numbers should mention your options. Also, instead of checking all the numbers less than `num / 2`, you can check all the numbers less than `sqrt(n)`. If you cache the value of `sqrt(n)`, it should be faster.

Comment: In addition to the tips of @Carcigenicate: you can avoid the calculation of the square root completely by using the condition `i*i <= num`

Comment: Re: "I didn't create array instead of pointers because pointer operations are faster": There are so many things wrong with this statement that I hardly know where to begin. :-/

Comment: You're using the uninitialized variable `t` to calculate the size of your arrays **before** you assign a value to `t`.

Comment: Your code is really strange to me!!! You use an `malloc` on a area size which is computed with an uninitialized variable (`t`). I am really doubtful that: (1) It really worth to use an `malloc()` here; (2) It gives a *safe* result at the end (note that you do not free the allocated memory area).

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Ah, thanks for noticing this too! :-)

Comment: http://ideone.com/LIlszV: Runtime error time: 0 memory: 9432 signal:11

Comment: http://ideone.com/LIlszV - accepted :D

Comment: I did it without using pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Carcigenicate suggests, you're exceeding the time limit because your prime generator is too slow; and it's too slow since you're using an inefficient algorithm.

Indeed, you should not simply test each consecutive number for primality (which, by the way, you're also doing ineffectively), but rather rule out multiple values at once using known primes (and perhaps additional primes which you compute). For example, you don't need to check multiples of 5 and 10 (other than the actual value 5) for primality, since you know that 5 divides them. So just "mark" the multiples of various primes as irrelevant.

... and of course, that's just for getting you started, there are all sort of tricks you could use for optimization - algorithmic and implementation-related.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are looking for algorithm improvements, but the following technical optimizations might help:

If you are using Visual Studio, you can use alloca instead of malloc, so that n and m go in the stack instead of the heap.

You can also try to rewrite your algorithm using arrays instead of pointers to put n and m in the stack.

If you want to keep using pointers, use the __restrict keyword after the asterisks, which alerts the compiler that you don't make references of the two pointers.

Comment: Note that there's no way to recover if `alloca()` fails to allocate.  Also, your stack is limited (e.g. to 1 MiB on WIndows, I believe; it's only 8 MiB on Unix, and the Windows value is smaller), whereas `malloc()` can allocate gigabytes on many systems.  (And, for whatever it's worth, `alloca()` is available via GCC, and AFAIK was available in GCC before it was added to MSVS.  It doesn't affect me; I don't use it.)

Comment: Actually, on Windows you can recover from `alloca()` failing (using structured exception handling; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx has an example).  Still not a good idea (especially if you care about portability)… using alloca here won't speed things up appreciably.  If you really want to stick with the naive approach the best thing to do would be to parallelize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it without using pointers or arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int is_prime(long n){
    if (n == 1 || n % 2 == 0)
        return 0;
    if (n == 2)
        return 1;
    for (long i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i += 2) {
        if(n % i == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--) {
        long n, m;
        scanf("%ld %ld",&n,&m);

        for (long i = n; i <= m; i++) {
            if (is_prime(i) == 1)
            printf("%ld\n",i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to improve the primality check for an integer `n`. Here are a few that you might find useful.

1. **Reduce the number of checks**: A well known theorem is giving the fact that if you want to look for factors of `n`, let say `n = a * b`, then you can look for a divisor between `1` and `sqrt(n)`. (Proof is quite easy, the main argument being that we have three cases, either `a = b = sqrt(n)`, or we have `a < sqrt(n) < b` or `b < sqrt(n) < a`. And, whatever case we fall in, there will be a factor of `n` between `1` and `sqrt(n)`).
2. **Use a Sieve of Eratosthenes**: This way allows to discard unnecessary candidates which are previously disqualified (see [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (Wikipedia))
3. **Use probabilistic algorithms**: The most efficient way to check for primality nowadays is to use a probabilistic test. It is a bit more complex to implements but it is way more efficient. You can find a few of these techniques [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Probabilistic_tests) (Wikipedia).